# Can't access row elements in Python 2d array?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I have created a 2d matrix using Scipy's coo_matrix, and have a matrix M as such:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["hub", "auth", "weight"])
M = coo_matrix((df.iloc[:,2], (df.iloc[:,0],df.iloc[:,1])), shape=(len(hubs) + len(auths), len(hubs) + len(auths)))
M = M.todense()

[[0 0 0 1 1 1 0]
[0 0 0 1 1 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 1]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

I can successfully slice the array to get its columns and the elements in each column:

```
col = M[:,3]
val = col[0]
```

where val is equal to 1. I try to do something similar to extract a row:

```
row = M[0]
val = row[2]
```

which should also return 1, but instead val returns

```
[[0 0 0 1 1 1 0]]
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: it should return 0 , third element of first row...it works fine for me with matrix: [[0, 0 , 0, 1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], etc.]

Comment: What exactly is `M`? How did you construct it? Please include the code. If it is a `coo_matrix`, then it cannot be indexed or sliced. If it is a Numpy array, then `val` must be 0.

Comment: I constructed a coo_matrix from a dataframe object. \n

Comment: df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["0", "1", "2"])

Comment: M = coo_matrix((df.iloc[:,2], (df.iloc[:,0],df.iloc[:,1])), shape=(len(zero) + len(one), len(zero) + len(one)))
M = M.todense()

Comment: So, is `M` a NumPy array? Then `val` cannot be what you say it is. Please double check your example.

Comment: M is not a Numpy array, it is a coo_matrix. How can I access row elements in a coo_matrix?

Comment: It is not a coo_matrix, it is a `numpy.matrixlib.defmatrix.matrix` (because you called `todense`). Then the value of your first `val` must be `matrix([[1]])`, not 1, and the second `val` cannot be calculated because of the `IndexError`.  There is a lot of inconsistency in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a numpy array (as DYZ pointed it that `.todense()` is called on the original coo_matrix):

Notice that your original matrix, or 2d array is 7 x 7 (7 rows by 7 columns). When you call `col = M[:,3]`, you are saying you want the 3rd column and all rows, which is a resulting 7 x 1 matrix (7 rows by 1 column). When you call `col[2]`, you are actually calling `col[2,:]` or getting the 2nd row (which is now just a 1 x 1 matrix).

Now, if you call `row = M[0]`, you are actually calling `row = M[0,:]` or getting the 0th row and all columns, which is a 1 x 7 matrix (1 column by 7 rows). Thus calling `val = row[2]` gives an indexerror as you only have 1 row in your new matrix. You could instead call `val = row[:,2]` to get the 2nd column.

Comment: Please consider marking this problem with the checkmark to the left of the question if you think it is the best answer. Thanks!